# Chrome extension popup injecting javascript more than once

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, popup

I am just starting to learn how to make extensions...

I want it so that when the popup first opens, it injects javascript into the active tab. There are also some buttons in the popup that interact with the injected javascript.

The problem I am having is every time I open the popup, it injects the javascript into the active tab. Each time that happens, any saved variables are reset. So, I ended up just making a global variable to get around this issue.

Here is a sample of the code I am using:

popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>My Extension</title>
    <link href="popup.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="controls">
        <div class="action1">action 1</div>
        <div class="action2">action 2</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

popup.js

```
var command = {
    action1 : function(){
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
            code: 'myExtension("action1");'
        });
    },
    action2 : function(){
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
            code: 'myExtension("action2");'
        });
    }
};

chrome.windows.getCurrent( function(win) {
    chrome.tabs.query({
        'windowId': win.id,
        'active': true
    }, function(tabArray) {

        // windows.done pretty much doesn't do anything
        if ( !window.done ) {
            chrome.tabs.insertCSS( tabArray[0].id, {
                file: 'myextension.css'
            });

            chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
                file: 'myextension.js'
            }, function(){
                window.done = true;
                chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
                    code: 'myExtension("init");'
                });
            });
        }

        // action1
        var el = document.querySelector( '.action1' );
        el.removeEventListener( 'click', commands.action1 );
        el.addEventListener( 'click', commands.action1 );

        // action2
        var el = document.querySelector( '.action2' );
        el.removeEventListener( 'click', commands.action2 );
        el.addEventListener( 'click', commands.action2 );

    });
});
```

In my `myextension.js` file, I do something like this so I don't lose internal variables that I need to save:

```
(function(){

  window.myExtension = function( command ) {
    if ( typeof myExtensionVariables === 'undefined' ) {
      window.myExtensionVariables = {
        que   : [],
        flags : {}
      }
    }
    if ( command === 'init' ) {
      // initialize!
    }

    // etc

  };

})();
```

I don't think I have a need for a `background.html` or `background.js`,

What I would really like is to prevent javascript injection from happening more than once.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the size of the injected content script is a problem then inject a small code to check the state:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript({code: "window.myExtensionVariables"}, function(result) {
    if (!result[0]) {
        /* inject the script */
    }
});
```

The global variable `myExtensionVariables` isn't a problem because only your injected content script sees it, not the webpage.

As for `window.done` in the popup script, `window` refers to the popup miniwindow, not the webpage, so indeed it's useless for the task.

Overall I'd stick with your implementation because it's the simplest one. Otherwise you'd have to track `webNavigation` events and maintain a list of tab ids with injected scripts in `chrome.storage` or a persistent background page.

Comment: Oh! I didn't realize that `executeScript` had a parameter in the callback. Awesome, thanks!

Comment: You did forget the `null` before the `{code:...}` though - I'll edit your answer ;)

Comment: @Mottie, it's an optional parameter, you don't have to specify it.

Comment: Yes, but that is what I needed to prevent injection!

Comment: I mean since it's optional there's no difference between omitting it or using `null` or `undefined`. Chrome API isn't standard js in this aspect as it allows to omit positional parameters.